# Magento 2 - add custum attribute to urlrewrite programmatically

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, url-rewrite, magento2.3

I am trying to regenerate the urlrewrites on magento 2.3.
They are now created by the pruducts name

> /artist.html

but i would like to to add some custom attributes.

> /astist-title-format.html

to have them unique & to prevent the error:

> The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists.

any help would be appreciated!